# What determines the specific version of ASP.NET Core and the corresponding assembly versions that are used when running an ASP.NET Core app?

Tags: asp.net-core

Assuming that you are using `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`in your `.csproj` file, the documentation says that you should reference the ASP.NET Core framework through a shared framework reference like so:

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

The`.csproj` file will also contain a target framework reference. For example, `netcoreapp3.1` is specified using the following target framework moniker:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

What isn't clear to me is how the specific version of *ASP.NET Core* is selected. I understand that the .NET runtime version selection process is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) but I don't understand how the *ASP.NET Core web framework* version is selected. For example, what if I wanted to experiment with different features between two versions of ASP.NET Core that targeted the same version of .NET Core or .NET? How would that be distinguished?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file),and use `#if {version}` to separate TFM-dependent code.

Answer (score 0):

When you target `netcoreapp3.1` and you have multiple 3.1.x installed (e.g., you have `3.1.15`, `3.1.20` and `3.1.28` installed), the latest version `3.1.28` will be used. Currently no known way to tell the .csproj to pick up a specific version (correct me if any).

For your question

> what if I wanted to experiment with different features between two
> versions of ASP.NET Core that targeted the same version of .NET Core
> or .NET?

the only way I can think of is that you need to have couple build boxes installed with different point releases so that you can try for example `3.1.20` and `3.1.28`.